# Is it possible to define the Kronecker symbol $\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)$ using some sort of arithmetic in a manner similar to the Legendre symbol?

Tags: number-theory

And if so, what does it say about the cases some mathematicians prefer to leave undefined?

As you all well know, $$\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) = a^{\frac{p - 1}{2}} \pmod{p}$$ for $p$ an odd prime. This makes it possible to compute Legendre symbols on an ordinary scientific calculator (to some extent). But for the Kronecker symbol, one has to either memorize the cases or constantly refer to the book. Is there some way to do, for example, $\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)$ or $\left(\frac{17}{2}\right)$ on a calculator and get the `1` or `-1` answer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. But before I get to it, let's review the usual definition:

- $\left( \frac{a}{2} \right) = -1$ if $a \equiv 5 \pmod 8$
- $\left( \frac{a}{2} \right) = 0$ if $a \equiv 0 \pmod 4$
- $\left( \frac{a}{2} \right) = 1$ if $a \equiv 1 \pmod 8$

This is Definition 10.2.1 in Alaca & Williams's *Introductory Algebraic Number Theory*.

Take the parity bit of $a$, if that's 0, you're done, because then $\left(\frac{a}{2}\right) = 0$. Otherwise, compute $(-1)^{\lfloor \frac{a + 1}{4} \rfloor}.$ The full formula then is $$(a \pmod 2)(-1)^{\large{\lfloor \frac{a + 1}{4} \rfloor}}.$$

Now let's make sure this works with the definition given above. If $a \equiv 5 \pmod 8$, then $a + 1 \equiv 6 \pmod 8$ so $\lfloor \frac{a + 1}{4} \rfloor$ is odd, so the power of $-1$ is $-1$ as desired. But if $a \equiv 1 \pmod 8$ then $a + 1 \equiv 2 \pmod 8$ so $\lfloor \frac{a + 1}{4} \rfloor$ is even, and the power of $-1$ is 1 as desired.

But I think it would be much easier to just memorize $1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0$, or, easier still, $1, -1, -1, 1$.

The definition from Alaca & Williams leaves $a \equiv \{2, 3, 6, 7\} \pmod 8$ undefined. By the arithmetic method I've described here, $\left( \frac{a}{2} \right) = 0$ if $a$ is even, regardless of divisibility by 4, and

- $\left( \frac{a}{2} \right) = -1$ if $a \equiv 3 \pmod 8$
- $\left( \frac{a}{2} \right) = 1$ if $a \equiv 7 \pmod 8$.

Comment: You need to change an instance of $n$ to $a$.

Comment: Oh, yes, thank you, I've made the change.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question I can only copy what Bob wrote: $$\left(\frac{a}{2}\right) = (a \pmod 2)(-1)^{\large{\lfloor \frac{a + 1}{4} \rfloor}}.$$ But for the second and more important part of your question, I have to ask you what it is that you want the Kronecker symbol to accomplish.

If $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a})}$ is a unique factorization domain, then the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$ reliably tells us whether the odd prime $p$ is inertial, ramifies or splits in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a})}$.

The Kronecker symbol $\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)$ as defined above does not reliably tell us whether $2$ is inertial, ramifies or splits in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a})}$. Observe, for example, that $\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) = -1$, yet $(-1)(1 - \sqrt{3})(1 + \sqrt{3}) = 2$. Or how $\left(\frac{6}{2}\right) = 0$, yet $(-1)(2 - \sqrt{6})(2 + \sqrt{6}) = 2$.